# Ruby on Rails - How can I resolve this 'rake db:create' error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am trying to get a simple tutorial app up and running with Rails, but have run into this problem almost right away. I create the new ruby app, `cd` to the directory and run `rake db:create`. I get the following

`Please install the sqlite3 adapter: 'gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to the Gemfile.)`

But I do have the gem added to the Gemfile, like so:

`gem 'sqlite3'`

Also, when I tried to gem install the adapter, I was given an output saying that it did not exist in any repository. This is my first time using rails, any ideas on how to fix this?

*Edit
`gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` produces the following:

`Error: Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' in any repository.`

The it offers some alternatives, only one of them being sqlite3. It is called `activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter`. Is this the one I need possibly?

Comment: Did you do `bundle install`?

Comment: try running `bundle`, and if that doesn't work, run `gem install bundler`, and then `bundle`

Comment: Yes, I did run bundle install and everything seemed to install fine.

Comment: I used to RoR installer for windows which came with bundler.

Comment: what happens when you do `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`?

Comment: What rubygems version are you using? there was a bug in 2.0.1 similar to this if I remember correctly.

Comment: what does running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's input. I never was able to resolve this issue, and ended up just using the [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/) instead. So much easier, just make sure you delete all your previous versions of Rails, Ruby, Gems, everything. Then use the installer.